# Is Repository Project useful in C#?

Tags: c#, architecture

Our company is against the Generic Repository and Unit of Work in C#, which makes sense. Since Entity Framework Core already completes those functions.

However, I'm reading articles that a Repository is not even needed. We have a Repository C# project to isolate files from other Application services (including Parsing of Files, and Sending emails). This prevents everything from being mixed into 1 service. So How do people against the Repository, work with isolating data access code?

Comment: see [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)

Comment: @marksmith542 Please be a bit more specific. Your question is too generic.

Comment: _"So How do people against the Repository, work with isolating data access code?"_ Using a DAL is one option. It's possible your Repository is really just a DAL  'Repository Pattern vs DAL', https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291344/repository-pattern-vs-dal